# Where to place non functional tasks in user story map

Tags: agile, requirements, user-story

I am new with the user story map approach, I started with to compose the stories to be implemented from user perspective, and it seems very promising.

However, I am not sure about the non-functional stories, how to place them within the story map. Especially when are talking from user perspective, that is not aware of these details (e.g. performance, stability, etc...)

Comment: The product owner is a user, and, as such, is entitled to to his or her own stories that address maintenance costs, reliability, availability, etc.: "Given a single application deployment container, when loading reaches 50%, then the application supervisor spins up a second deployment."\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User stories work best when you don't have to worry about all the non-functional stuff people 'just assume will work'

The best way to deal with this is to first setup your basic environment/architecture framework. ie

"We are making a website, ergo we will need our standard microsoft stack, IIS + C# + Asp.net + MVC + MSSQL with the usual OAuth2 roles bases auth, Load balancing, Monitoring, Firewall etc etc etc, deployed to Azure"

This will answer 90% of the non-functional requirements. If you are doing something in the standard framework, then they come as standard.

If you have a special non-functional, say "Long running custom process must be able to handle workload X" then you should call it out as a User Story. "As the accounts team, we need the end of year report to be completed within X days"